# Assistance displaying a scroll-bar onto a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Well basically I don't know what's wrong with my code, i'm trying to put a scrollbar onto a JTextAre but the JTextArea just keeps resizing instead of the scrollbar going into action.I have declared "t1" as a private JTextArea field and "s1" as a private JScrollPane field. I also have some GridBagConstraints, "jp" is the JPanel. Here's my code: `

```
gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    t1 = new JTextArea(5,15);
    s1 = new JScrollPane(t1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    jp.add(s1,gbc);
```

Comment: This must be a problem in the code you have *not* shown. If I put this (adding GridBagConstraint gbc = new GridBagConstraint();) into a class extending JPanel and add this to a JFrame, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm adding it to a JPanel, my class extends JFrame, maybe that's the problem? EDIT: no, that wasn't it.

Comment: Sorry, my grammar... I have a JPanel subclass where I do this.add(s1,gbc) and this JPanel object is added to a JFrame. (JFrame contains JPanel contains scrolled JTextArea). Added the demo using an answer.

Comment: Your grammar is fine, and you're right, there's something wrong with my code because that code fragment works fine.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo as it works:

```
public class White extends JPanel {
    public White(){
        setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=2;
        JTextArea t1 = new JTextArea(5,15);
        JScrollPane s1 = new JScrollPane(t1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.add(s1,gbc);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new White() );
        frame.setTitle( "Hello World" );
        frame.setSize( 600, 400 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```